# Suppress Webpack 2 + ESLint extra output (stack trace)

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, eslint, webpack-2

I'm migrating a project from `create-react-app` to a custom Webpack 2 configuration, and so far I have everything working as it was in the CRA version except for ESLint output.

I'm used to seeing the following...

#### Expected Output:

```
WARNING in ./src/apps/NotesApp/components/Replies/ReplyEditor.js

./src/apps/NotesApp/components/Replies/ReplyEditor.js
  17:1  warning  Line 17 exceeds the maximum line length of 120  max-len

✖ 1 problem (0 errors, 1 warning)
```

But now I'm getting a full stack trace that makes these warnings take up 2 - 3 times as much console/terminal space.

#### Evil Output:

```
WARNING in ./src/apps/NotesApp/components/Replies/ReplyEditor.js

./src/apps/NotesApp/components/Replies/ReplyEditor.js
  17:1  warning  Line 17 exceeds the maximum line length of 120  max-len

✖ 1 problem (0 errors, 1 warning)

 @ ./src/apps/NotesApp/components/Replies/Replies.js 3:0-40
 @ ./src/apps/NotesApp/components/Replies/ReplyPanel.js
 @ ./src/apps/NotesApp/components/Note.js
 @ ./src/apps/NotesApp/components/NotesList.js
 @ ./src/apps/NotesApp/containers/NotesModal.js
 @ ./src/apps/NotesApp/components/NotesApp.js
 @ ./src/apps/NotesApp/index.js
 @ ./build/buildImport.js
 @ ./src/apps/AppsLibrary/LibraryRoutes.js
 @ ./src/index.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000 webpack/hot/dev-server (webpack)-dev-server/client?/ (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js react-hot-loader/patch ./src/index
```

---

### What I've tried...

The following `webpack.config.js` options got rid of all output completely (which I don't want):

1. `devServer: { stats: 'none' }`
2. `devServer: { quiet: true }`
3. `devServer: { stats: { warnings: false }}`

Every other option for `devServer.stats` had no effect on the stack trace.

And just to see if ESLint was creating the stack traces, I set a custom formatter to return blank:

```
rules: [
  {
    enforce: 'pre',
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'eslint-loader',
    options: { formatter: message => '' }
  }
]
```

...which has the following output:

```
WARNING in ./src/apps/NotesApp/components/Replies/ReplyEditor.js
ESLintError
 @ ./src/apps/NotesApp/components/Replies/Replies.js 3:0-40
 @ ./src/apps/NotesApp/components/Replies/ReplyPanel.js
 @ ./src/apps/NotesApp/components/Note.js
 @ ./src/apps/NotesApp/components/NotesList.js
 @ ./src/apps/NotesApp/containers/NotesModal.js
 @ ./src/apps/NotesApp/components/NotesApp.js
 @ ./src/apps/NotesApp/index.js
 @ ./build/buildImport.js
 @ ./src/apps/AppsLibrary/LibraryRoutes.js
 @ ./src/index.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000 webpack/hot/dev-server (webpack)-dev-server/client?/ (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js react-hot-loader/patch ./src/index
```

The node.js execution of WebpackDevServer creates a `stats` object with all of the errors, warnings, and other information about the devServer, and each of the `stats.warnings` is a message formatted for shell like this:

```
"./src/apps/NotesApp/components/Replies/ReplyEditor.js

[4m./src/apps/NotesApp/components/Replies/ReplyEditor.js[24m
  [2m17:1[22m  [33mwarning[39m  Line 17 exceeds the maximum line length of 120  [2mmax-len[22m

[33m[1m✖ 1 problem (0 errors, 1 warning)
[22m[39m
 @ ./src/apps/NotesApp/components/Replies/Replies.js 3:0-40
 @ ./src/apps/NotesApp/components/Replies/ReplyPanel.js
 @ ./src/apps/NotesApp/components/Note.js
 @ ./src/apps/NotesApp/components/NotesList.js
 @ ./src/apps/NotesApp/containers/NotesModal.js
 @ ./src/apps/NotesApp/components/NotesApp.js
 @ ./src/apps/NotesApp/index.js
 @ ./build/buildImport.js
 @ ./src/apps/AppsLibrary/LibraryRoutes.js
 @ ./src/index.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000 webpack/hot/dev-server (webpack)-dev-server/client?/ (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js react-hot-loader/patch ./src/index"
```

...which makes it look like I could just intercept the messages and do something like `stats.warnings.map(message => message.replace(/^\s*(at|@)+.*\n*/gm, ''))`, but that has zero effect also.

Does anyone know where this stack trace is being generated and if there's ANY way to turn it off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible from version 2.5.0 of webpack by setting moduleTrace: false in the stats object:

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    stats: {
        moduleTrace: false,
    },
};
```

Comment: Thanks for adding this feature! I'm still a little perplexed, though. I would think this would be included as `false` in `quiet: true` or `stats: false`, but it isn't yet. Also, this only gets rid of the output in the terminal, but my Chrome console still shows the offending "moduleTrace". Any idea why the behaviors are different?

Comment: You should open an issue around the defaults, I'm sure they would like to discuss before changing those. Depending on how you run the dev-server you need to set the same option for that as it doesn't seem to inherit the stats-part from the main config, not sure why that is.